# Intuitive explanation for Hardy-Littlewood maximal function

Tags: cv.complex-variables

I came across the Hardy-Littlewood maximal function in an analysis course. Could someone help me intuitively understood what the purpose of this map is, and why it is useful?

Thank you.

Regards
Akarsh